# Android Studio 2020.3.1 - Run very slow, always re-build

Tags: android-studio

I'm using latest AS, version 2020.3.1. Every time I change the code and run it again, AS run very slow, always re-build project (take about 10 minutes). My project is also quite large, using many libraries.

How to make AS run faster?

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your system configurations. It does not matter which android studio version you are using. Try upgrading your machine or prevent using inbuilt AVD of android studio rather use your own mobile for testing. This could make Your AS run a bit faster.
Here is the link to know how it is done
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device